# Definite integral of a constant function except at one of the bounds

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f(y)$ by defined as $0$ for $y \leq 1$ and $2$ for $y > 1$.

How would I show that this integral: $\int_1^2 f(x,y) \, dy = 2$?

If $f(y) = 2$ everywhere, then obviously the integral would be equal to $2$, but I can't just evaluate it using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: This is a step function, the integral is just the area of a rectangle 2x1

Answer (score 3):

You may just write
$$
\int_{1}^{2} f(x,y) \:dy=\int_{\large]1,2]} f(x,y) \:dy=\int_{1}^{2} 2 \:dy=\left[2y\vphantom{\frac11}\right]_1^2=2\times(2-1)=2.
$$

Comment: That's what I thought. Would I have to make some note about the nature of an integral (area) along with this?